# proper opcache configuration for CLI

Tags: php, opcache

what is the proper opcache configuration when using PHP for CLI only?

I find very confusing/old resources and am not sure this is the proper conf:

```ini
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.file_cache=/tmp/php-opcache
```

More specifically: the doc describe `opcache.file_cache` as a second level cache, SHM memory being the 1st level. But I can't find any recent resource indicating whether the SHM memory is shared across PHP's cli invocations depending on this, either `opcache.file_cache` isn't nescessary or `opcache.file_cache_only` is required.

Secondly, I'd like to determine the required management over the content of the directory  that `opcache.file_cache` points to

- it should be created beforehand with the proper rights
- should it be emptied of old files manually?
- ...

Comment: On linux, you should set file_cache_only = 1

Comment: Thank, you very much @shingo! Do you have any resource/explanation backing this very appreciated answer, please? :D

Comment: Nope. You can benchmark the execution time with different options.

Comment: To your question about SHM in CLI, I think [Nikita’s blog post](https://www.npopov.com/2021/10/13/How-opcache-works.html) gives a great answer: “Windows is the only platform where two unrelated PHP processes can share the same opcache SHM. For example, it’s possible for two concurrent CLI invocations to share the same cache, which is not possible on other operating systems. The opcache.cache_id setting exists to force a different cache in this case.”

Comment: @ChrisHaas Perfect! So, for Linux CLI usage, `opcache.file_cache_only=1` should improve performance. Remains the correct administration of the `opcache.file_cache` directory (ie: are old entries evicted automatically by PHP or should we do it)

Comment: @Bruno, one thing you might never use, but should at least be aware of, both [`opcache_reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php) and [`opcache_invalidate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php), and possibly others say in their documentation that they only affect in-memory cache and not file cache.

Comment: "are old entries evicted automatically by PHP or should we do it" - If we consider "old" to be "no longer used", my guess is that PHP does **not** prune those files. There is `max_wasted_percentage` but I think it is only for the memory cache. These are just my educated guesses, however, and they shouldn't be considered authoritative in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chris Haas comments, I've got some informations, but don't consider this answer as comprehensive: there are a lot of unknown around using the opcache for CLI.

Properly enabling the opcache for CLI **only** require this conf:

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.file_cache=/tmp/php-opcache
opcache.file_cache_only=1
```

notes:

- you must also configure another settings like `opcache.validate_timestamps`/`opcache.revalidate_freq`, but the choice will depend for example of your environment (dev/prod)
- some php function won't work, like opcache_reset()/opcache_invalidate()  this is counter intuitive, so be cautious!
- some settings are probably ignored, like `max_wasted_percentage` (just to be clear: the doc don't state this, it's just an educated guess)
- you will have to administrate the directory that `opcache.file_cache` point to:
- it must exist, and be writable by the current user
- you probably have to delete prune files older than X in this directory

interesting ressources:

- https://www.npopov.com/2021/10/13/How-opcache-works.html
- https://pierre-schmitz.com/using-opcache-to-speed-up-your-cli-scripts/
- (for french speakers) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EG-94iDNGMM

Personally, I convinced my team to not enable this feature "opcache for CLI", because I think there a too much dark corners.